# Getting a record's guid before save operation

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I need to use the GUID of a record. If the record is old, i can access to the guid with

```
Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
```

The issue is that I need to use the ID in the same moment that a new record is saved.

I try to save the record, reload the page and then use the id with

```
parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
window.location.reload(true);
var currentCaseId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
```

but it does not work.

Edit: I change my code so now I can get the ID in the onLoad event but now my problem is that I can only get the GUID if the user select "Save" (cause "save" button refresh the page). If the user select "Save&Close" or "Save&New" the record doesn't refresh so the onLoad event doesn't happen and I can't get the GUID.

Comment: No, you wont get the GUID in the next statement after refreshing the form. Until and unless that JScript execution completed, we can't get it. But you can get it in OnLoad script.

Comment: Thanks, this help my with one of my cases

Comment: @DenLun Please check one of the replies as an answer or explain what more you need to know to have your question satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a *guid* for an instance first when you actually create it. So, you need to actually perform the save operation before the server returns to you with the *guid*.

If you need to do something to the entity just before it's being saved (or maybe after the save but before postback to the client) you might want to intercept the operation using a plugin.

The optimal approach will depend on the actual need and that's depending on the reason for you trying to get to the *guid* in the first place. What exactly do you intend to do with the "early *guid*"?

Does it have to be in JavaScript at all?

Comment: I follow your advice and i use a plugin. At first I dind't wanted cause I'm a newbie with CRM Dynamics and I've never created one but it  was a lot easier that way. Thanks.

Comment: @DenLun In my opinion, plugins are far easier than JavaScript-coding. And cleaner in the code. However, there's a certain threshold and some gotchas to pass, I need to admit. But once you've passed that, it's much nicer (once again - YMMV). I've put a setup for a plugin on my blog a fee months ago - why don't you take a look. I'm not going to give you the URL because I don't want to self-promote but I can tell you that it's on WordPress and has to do with my name. He who googleth, he will find. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a record in crm the primary key is created by crm and is returned to you. You can create a guid yourself and assigning it before saving. Now you know the Key on forehand.

Answer (score 1):

If the record is in create mode I am using JavaScript and XrmServiceToolkit to create new record with all posible attributes. This gives me the needed GUID for another actions in the background. Then I prevent save of the original form and open the newly created record in the same window. It looks exactly the same as regular saving, but it does what you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. This might not be the industry best practise, but it works: I do the autosave (Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();) before user has a chance to save(andclose or saveandnew). I do the autosave after user has entered all required fields. Guid is then generated and usable on the onload-event.